# Kubernetes create StatefulSet with image pull secret?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

For Kubernetes Deployment we can specify imagePullSecrets to allow it to pull Docker images from our private registry. But as far as I can tell, StatefulSet doesn't support this?

**How can I supply a pullsecret to my StatefulSet?**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  serviceName: redis-service
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      # imagePullSecrets not valid here for StatefulSet :-(
      containers:
        - image: {{ .Values.image }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StatefulSet` supports `imagePullSecrets`. You can check it as follows.

```
$ kubectl explain statefulset.spec.template.spec --api-version apps/v1
:
   imagePullSecrets <[]Object>
     ImagePullSecrets is an optional list of references to secrets in the same
     namespace to use for pulling any of the images used by this PodSpec. If
     specified, these secrets will be passed to individual puller
     implementations for them to use. For example, in the case of docker, only
     DockerConfig type secrets are honored. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod
:
```

For instance, you can try if the following sample `StatefulSet` can create in your cluster first.

```
$ kubectl create -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: YOUR-PULL-SECRET-NAME
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
EOF

$ kubectl get pod web-0 -o yaml | \
  grep -E '^[[:space:]]+imagePullSecrets:' -A1
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: YOUR-PULL-SECRET-NAME
```

Comment: Strange.. I didn't know that explain command, that is very useful thanks!

Comment: I tried adding this again, and can't get it to work.. I'm using Jetbrains Webstorm with a Kubernetes plugin to get syntax highlighting in yaml files, and I get the following warning when adding imagePullSecrets:
Key 'imagePullSecrets' is not expected here. core.v1.PodTemplateSpec <Kubernetes v1.19.x>. I also got an errormessage when trying to upgrade with helm: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on vn-redis/templates/statefulset.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: found character that cannot start any token. Any ide on what's going on here? =)

Comment: I was able to work around this, adding my pullsecret to the default service account: kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "pullsecret"}]}'. But I would prefer to define this secret in my Helm chart..

Comment: It's odd. I also tested and added the output in my answer either.  I could create my answer's statefulset sample on my k8s 1.19 without issue.

Comment: I think something is up with my editor.. It appears to insert tabs in stead of spaces in the yaml file.. editing the file in another editor fixed it. + intellisense from my kubernetes plugin must be borked.. Your answer works when using another editor.